# Error on starting play 2.5.18 application

Tags: java, playframework, akka

We just migrated to play 2.5.18.
The code changes are done but after upgradation the jvm is shutting down with the below mentioned error. 
Any idea what this is about? It’s been a week and I have been stuck on this.

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)

Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6]: play/libs/F$Function, shutting down JVM since ‘akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error’ is enabled for for ActorSystem[application]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/libs/F$Function
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
at play.core.j.DefaultJavaHandlerComponents.getAction(JavaAction.scala:142)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$6.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$6.apply(JavaAction.scala:89)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foldLeft(ArraySeq.scala:46)
at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:89)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

As asked, I am adding my application.conf
My application.conf is given below:

```
play.crypto.secret = "xyz"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs = "en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
#application.global = Global
play.application.loader = "CustomApplicationLoader"
# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/routes`)
play.http.router = x.Routes
play.http.context = "/x/v1"

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
evolutionplugin = disabled
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer = 512k

ebean.x = "models.ebean.x.*"


logger.file = logback.xml
include "re.constants.conf"
include "akka.conf"
include "metering.conf"
include "basicAuth.conf"
include "cache.conf"
include "awsS3bucketCredentials.conf"

play.evolutions.enabled=false
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
```

The Module.java looks like this:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {


    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StartUpHandler.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

StartupHandler.java looks something like this:

```
@Singleton
public class StartUpHandler {

    private Injector injector;

    @Inject
    public StartUpHandler() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new ControllersModule(), new ServicesModule(), new RepositoryModule());
/*Some code*/

    }
```

CustomApplicationLoader looks like this:

```
public class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {


    @Override
    public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {
        Logger.error("GuiceApplicationBuilder builder");
        Configuration updatedConfig = context.initialConfiguration();
        File file = new File(".");
        String mode = updatedConfig.getString("mode");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mode)) {
            try {
                File modeFolder = FileUtils.getFile(file, "conf/" + mode);
                if (modeFolder.exists()) {
                    play.api.Configuration modeConfig = context.initialConfiguration().getWrappedConfiguration();
                    IOFileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.conf");
                    Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFiles(modeFolder, fileFilter, null);
                    for (File confFile : fileList) {
                        modeConfig = modeConfig
                                .$plus$plus(new play.api.Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)));

                    }
                    updatedConfig = new Configuration(modeConfig);
                    Logger.error("Folder: " + modeFolder);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error("GLOBAL: Exception while loading configuration for mode : " + mode, e);
            }
        } else {
            Logger.error("GLOBAL: Please provide mode in which play application has to start (Ex. play -Dmode=<mode>) ");
        }

        return initialBuilder
                .in(context.environment())
                .loadConfig(updatedConfig)
                .overrides(overrides(context));
    }
```

Comment: post your config. as a starting point ie. application.conf

Comment: I have added the application.conf and the startup files.